# Impress.js Menu by Ralt

Tags: menu, navigation, custom-font, impress.js

I've managed to create an impress.js presentation and have added the menu created by Ralt (https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/pull/153)
However, what i'm trying to do now and can't seem to be able to get through is changing the font of the menu and the menu titles to a custom font of my choice (@font/font-family function doesn't seem to work for me) and also being able to change the actual navigation/menu button for it to display an image of my choice instead of just a word of text as currently setup...

Help anyone ??

Thanks!!

Ruds

Comment: Ok i've solved my problem....little error in my coding...still quite new at this stuff....